# AS3- ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property not found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can someone tell me why I get this error?

ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property roll_mc not found on com.usmanzubairi.theAges.TheAges and there is no default value.
    at com.usmanzubairi.theAges::PirGame/rolling()

```
package com.usmanzubairi.theAges
{  
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.media.*;

public class TheAges extends MovieClip
{
    private var game:PirGame;
    private var game2:PreGame;
    private var game3:SupGame;


    public function TheAges()
    {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
    }


    private function startGame(event:Event):void
    {
        if (event.target != player_btn)
        {
                removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);

                game = new PirGame();
                addChild(game);
        }

        else
        {
                addChild(player_mc);
                player_mc.visible = true;
                player_mc.play();
        }

                    if (event.target == player_mc.tom_mc)
                    {
                        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);

                        game2 = new PreGame();
                        addChild(game2);
                    }

                    if (event.target == player_mc.pete_mc)
                    {
                        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);

                        game = new PirGame();
                        addChild(game);
                    }

                    if(event.target == player_mc.sam_mc)
                    {
                        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);

                        game3 = new SupGame();
                        addChild(game3);
                    }

    }   

    public function gameOver():void
    {
        removeChild(game);
        game = null;
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
    }
}
```

}

Here's the PirGame document class code:

```
package com.usmanzubairi.theAges
{
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.net.SharedObject;

public class PirGame extends MovieClip
{
    public function PirGame() 
    {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,rolling);
    }

    private function rolling (event:Event):void
    {
        if (event.target == MovieClip(root).roll_mc)
        {
            addChild(roll)
            roll.visible = true;
            runner_mc.visible = false;
            roll.play();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: Are you going to say something about "roll" stuff? also what is roll_mc you've used in rolling() function...

Comment: "roll" is a rolling animation and "roll_mc" is the button that plays that rolling  animation.

Comment: are you sure roll_mc exists ? try test it before your condition to see the value (`if( MovieClip(root).roll_mc && event.target == MovieClip(root).roll_mc )`). If null, the object don't exists. Try debug your movie (ctrl+maj+enter) instead of running it (ctrl+enter), you will have better informations on the error and you could see all variables values a the error time.

Comment: @Binou, thanks. I had to define the movie clip in the class. So I added `public var roll_mc:MovieClip;`, after that I didn't get the error. However when I click the button the rolling animation doesn't play, it gets stuck and continues with the running animation. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: do you have a button named roll_mc on your stage in flash pro ? is it on the main stage or in an other symbol ? if your roll_mc is on your PirGame symbol you cannnot access it with `MovieClip(root).roll_mc`, if it is realy placed on the main stage you don't have to declare it with `public var roll_mc:MovieClip;`

Comment: @Binou, the roll_mc movie clip is inside the PirGame symbol, and the PirGame symbol is not on the stage, it is in the library.

Answer (score 2):

If your roll_mc is in your PirGame symbol, and i think Pirgame class is well associated with the symbol, try modify your PirGame class a s follow:

```
package com.usmanzubairi.theAges
{
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.net.SharedObject;

    public class PirGame extends MovieClip
    {
        public function PirGame() 
        {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,rolling);
        }

        private function rolling (event:Event):void
        {
            trace( event.target, roll_mc );
            // change MovieClip(root).roll_mc to this.roll_mc as roll_mc is on this symbol and not on the root.
            if( event.target == this.roll_mc )
            {
                trace( 'roll_mc clicked' );
                addChild( roll )
                roll.visible = true;
                runner_mc.visible = false;
                roll.play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you just want the roll_mc be clickable try the following:

```
package com.usmanzubairi.theAges
{
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.net.SharedObject;

    public class PirGame extends MovieClip
    {
        public function PirGame() 
        {
            if( roll_mc )   roll_mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, rolling );
            else            addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _onStage );
        }

        private function _onStage( e:Event ):void
        {
            removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _onStage );
            roll_mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, rolling );
        }

        private function rolling( e:Event ):void
        {
            trace( 'roll_mc clicked' );
            addChild( roll )
            roll.visible = true;
            runner_mc.visible = false;
            roll.play();
        }
    }
}
```

if you don't have to re display the runner_mc you can remove it from the display list instead of make it not visible:

```
removeChild( runner_mc );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used the code you sent me. However, although I get no errors, the animation still gets stuck and continues with the running animation. This is weird because I have seen the animation work properly before, prior to my **ReferenceError: Error #1069:**

Comment: do you have other object that can be clicked and detected in the rolling function ? if no you can add the mouseEvent click listener directly on roll_mc it's better.

Comment: I have added the traces to the comment, and in the output I get "roll_mc clicked", but the running animation still doesn't hide when the roll_mc button is clicked, instead it gets stuck and resumes playing. I have also tried the code you have given me, and received no errors, but the same animation problem. Could it be the problem is not in the PirGame, but another class? Thanks.

Comment: what is your roll clip where is it created ? what is your runner_mc clip where is it created ?

Comment: The roll clip is the rolling animation, it is in the library, but an instance of it is in the PirGame movieclip (PirGame movieclip is not on the stage, it is in the library and has the class called "PirGame"). runner_mc is the running animation, again it is in the library, but an instance of it is in the PirGame movieclip.

Comment: where did you add the roll clip in PirGame ? do the roll play well ? the problem is just the runner_mc stay visible ?

Comment: Yeah, the roll clip plays well and yes the runner_mc staying visible is the problem. This might be the reason why the animation gets stuck when I press the roll_mc button. This is where I added the roll clip in PirGame: `private function rolling( e:Event ):void
        {
            trace( 'roll_mc clicked' );
            addChild( roll )
            roll.visible = true;
            runner_mc.visible = false;
            roll.play();
        }`

Comment: Did you try the removeChild( runner_mc ) ? do you really have just one runner_mc clip on your PirGame library symbol ?

Comment: I added `removeChild(runner_mc)`, which didn't have an effect. Yes, I only have one runner_mc clip in my Pirgame library symbol.

Comment: it's really weird that `removeChild` didn't do anything. Try add `trace(runner_mc, runner_mc ? runner_mc.parent : null)` after the `removeChild` and paste the output please

Comment: This is the code:  `private function rolling (event:Event):void
    {
        if (event.target == roll_mc)
   {
    trace( 'roll_mc clicked' ); 
    addChild(roll)
    removeChild( runner_mc )
    trace(runner_mc, runner_mc ? runner_mc.parent : null)
    roll.visible = true;
    runner_mc.visible = false;
    roll.play();
   }`

This is the output:
**roll_mc clicked
[object Pete_run] null**

Comment: and after that the runner_mc clip is still visible ? realy weird as he has no more a parent so it is not on the display list anymore. Can't you join the fla to see ?

Comment: join the fla? Would you like me to post the fla file? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes i think it would be faster to find the solution ;)

Comment: Okay, so where do I upload the file?